# Jaspersoft studio summary and subreport

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a problem with jaspersoft studio, the problem is that I want to put the Subreport on the very last page in the document. So my idea was to put it in the summary, but then I got something strange...At the end of the PDF generation the subreport is on the last page, BUT the sub report is not complete there is stuff missing :/ It is just printing out the last values

Consider the following example:

I have 3 Parts, Part-1, Part-2, Part-3
After finishing the part-3 the subreport should be visualize with some of the information of part 1-3, but the subreport in the summary just contains information from the part 3

I use a XML Datasource

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think of the context of the summary band and the sub report.

Is a variable from part 1 and part 2 being passed to the sub report? Is the same variable being passed from part 3? If so then it is being overwritten.

It really depends on the source of the information for the sub report, but the timing and context are likely the culprits here. You may need to create three sets of variables to contain what you want or just pass something into the sub report and let it gather the information for the three parts on its own.